# Whats the point of pointers to member functions?

Tags: c++, function, pointer-to-member

When I get the address of a member function, I can't assign the address to a void*:

```
void* ptr = &object::function; // <-- doesn't work!
```

I understand that this is because member functions give you these weird pointer to members instead of just behaving like a normal function, but I don't understand why this is so.

Yes, the function has an extra argument for the this pointer. Yes, the function doesn't really make sense outside of the context of the relevant object. But in the end, the function is still at a specific memory address, just like every other function out there. Considering that, I don't understand why the language designers are making me jump through hoops just to get the memory address of a member function:

For normal function:

```
void function() { }
std::cout << (size_t)&function << '\n';
```

No funny business required for that, but for a member function:

```
struct object {
   void function() { }
}

void object::* ptr = &object::function;
std::cout << *(size_t*)&ptr << '\n';
```

It just gets weird for seemingly no reason. I sort of understand pointers to members in the context of member variables, where they don't actually have an address until you create an instance, so until then you use the pointer to member as a sort of pseudo pointer. But I don't understand pointers to member functions. They're still functions, why are they getting this weird special treatment, and what actual advantages do these pointers to member functions have?

Comment: You can't even do that with function pointers. Pointers, functions pointers, member pointers and member function pointers are all 4 incompatible types. And `(size_t)&function` is potentially a cast to integer of smaller size.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Just tested it, works absolutely fine. A function pointer is essentially just a pointer, and casting it to an integer is absolutely fine. Especially since size_t is guaranteed to be the same size as the pointer.

Comment: @nik Please define 'works'.  What exactly have you achieved / proved there?

Comment: @PaulSanders Compiles without errors, warnings, etc... and gives the expected result, which is that it outputs the address of the function in memory.

Comment: You can safely get and use pointer of a **static** member function, but not regular member function. Such function does not support `this` keyword, but can access to  private members of any instance of that class.

Comment: _it outputs the address of the function in memory_ How do you know that?

Comment: A `size_t`, or more correctly an `intptr_t` is the size of a data pointer. It's not guaranteed to be the size of a function pointer. Function pointer can be and on some architectures are bigger than data pointers.

Comment: @PaulSanders I can't point you to the exact spot in the specification where it says that, but I'm quite certain that it is not undefined behavior. It should give me the address. Why shouldn't it?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Good to know, but that doesn't change the original question, which is why the distinction between pointers to functions and pointers to member functions is even being made.

Comment: The answer is inheritance.  Namely multiple-inheritance and inheritance of polymorphic classes.  See [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040209-00/?p=40713) for a specific example from MSVC.

Comment: Ḿember function pointers need an object to be invoked, you have to provide the "this" to call them. The type reflects that.

Comment: A pointer-to-member-function has to have enough information to support calling a virtual function that's overridden in a derived class, and, even worse, a virtual function that's called from a virtual base. Nobody's trying to keep you from finding the address of a function (although that information isn't at all useful); it's just that a raw address can't support the basic operations that can be done with a pointer-to-member-function.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm finally starting to understand :) If pointers to member functions have to be larger to fit in more data, then it makes a lot of sense that there would be a specific type for them. Thanks.

Comment: @nik Yep, you're getting it now.  Printing `sizeof (my_member_function_pointer)` would be illuminating.

Answer (score 4):

Note that according to the C and C++ specs, you can't cast *any* function pointer to a `void*`.  It is a common extension to allow it for normal functions (and that extension is required by the POSIX standard, so is likely to remain common), but not so much for member function pointers.

The reason is that many implementations of member functions require additional fixups/lookup besides just calling the function implementation -- for a virtual function, you need to look up the implementation based on the dynamic type of `this` (usually a vtable lookup), and supporting mulitple inheritance may require some adjustment of `this` before calling the function.  So many implementations use a representation for a method pointer that is larger than a `void *` and can't fit in it.

Comment: The fact that you can't perform said cast (legally) is a bit of a hangover from the days of exotic architectures and segmented memory addressing (remember good old `les bx, foo`?).  These days, we live in saner times, thankfully, and it's very unlikely to get you into trouble.  But, as has been said in the comments, member function pointers are (a) different (size) and you can't cast those.

Answer (score 3):

> I can't assign the address to a void*
>
> but I don't understand why this is so.

The most direct explanation is that pointers to member function are not convertible to `void*`. The most direct explanation for that is that the language doesn't allow it. Pointers to members are not pointers (this applies to pointers to data members as well as pointers to member functions).

> the function is still at a specific memory address

It's not so simple. There may actually be many implementations of the member function if it is virtual, and each implementation will be in a different memory address. The language implementation must somehow ensure that when you call through a pointer to member function on a derived object, the correct override is called, with the correct address of `this` which isn't necessarily the address of the instance argument. This becomes even more complex when multiple inheritance is involved. A pointer to member function typically contains more information than merely a single address.

If you check the `sizeof` the pointer to member function in your language implementation, then you'll likely find that it is bigger than the size of `void*`. Anything converted to `void*` must be convertible back to the same value, which is not possible when the original type has larger state than `void*` can represent.

---

Side note 1: Conversion from pointer to function to `void*` is a conditionally supported feature, so that may not be possible on all (old, esoteric?) language implementations either.

Side note 2:

> ```
> std::cout << (size_t)&function << '\n';
> ```

Not only does this rely on the aforementioned conditional feature, but this also relies on conversion from `void*` to `std::size_t` being well defined. That's not guaranteed either. When you want to convert a pointer to an integer, you should prefer to use `std::uintptr_t` instead.

Side note 3:

> ```
> void object::* ptr = &object::function;
> ```

This is ill-formed. It looks like a pointer to data member of type `void`, which of course isn't allowed. I think you intended to write:

```
void (object::* ptr)() = &object::function;
```

Side note 4:

> ```
> *(size_t*)&ptr
> ```

`&ptr` points to an object of type `void (object::*)()`, so reinterpreting it as `size_t*` and accessing the pointed object through the reinterpreted pointer results in undefined behaviour. Don't do this in a real program.

Answer (score 0):

> But in the end, the function is still at a specific memory address, just like every other function out there.

False. (Well, it is true that each function has a specific address, but the idea that there is always a single "the function" for a particular value of a pointer-to-member-function makes this false.)

A pointer-to-member does not store a specific memory address. Rather, it stores something that can be combined with an object of a correct type to produce a specific memory address.

As an example, the following code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// Define some types to use in the example
struct Base {
   void function() { std::cout << "Function\n"; }
   virtual void virtualFunction() { std::cout << "Base\n"; }
};
struct Derived : Base {
   void virtualFunction() override { std::cout << "Derived\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Base base;
    Derived derived;

    // Demonstrate pointing to a virtual function.
    void (Base::*pointer)() = &Base::virtualFunction;
    (base.*pointer)();
    (derived.*pointer)();

    // Demonstrate pointing to a non-virtual function.
    pointer = &Base::function;
    (base.*pointer)();
    (derived.*pointer)();
}
```

produces the following output

```
Base
Derived
Function
Function
```

The first two times that the variable `pointer` is invoked, two *different* functions are called, even though `pointer` did not change. This demonstrates that a pointer-to-member-function cannot simply hold the address of a single function. What it points to can depend on the object with which it is combined.

The second part of this example is to demonstrate that the same variable is equally capable of holding a pointer to a non-virtual function. The same type, even the same variable, needs to be able to handle both the case where dynamic dispatch is needed and the case where it is not. Simply storing the address of a non-virtual member function is insufficient since the value has to also contain the information "I do not point to a virtual function".

I tend to think of pointers-to-member as offsets. A pointer-to-data-member could be implemented as an offset into the object, and a pointer-to-member-function could be implemented as on offset into a virtual function table, where the vtable is viewed as being extended to also encompass the non-virtual member functions. If you have (the address of) an object of an acceptable type, then these offsets can be used (by the compiler) to get a specific address.

*Keep in mind that viewing pointers-to-members as offsets is just one approach (and not a particularly good one when it comes to handling member templates). Other approaches are possible, especially if `sizeof(pointer)` happens to be twice `sizeof(std::ptrdiff_t)`. So do not try to conclude that something must happen based upon this perspective.*