# C++ and pointer to function of class

Tags: c++

In c/c++ we made pointer of function

```
    __global__ void ckernel1(){

  printf("hello1\n");
}
```

and then

```
__device__ void (*pck1)() = ckernel1;
```

But when i want to do the same with pointer to struct or class function :

```
    struct x {
        int data_member;
        __device__ void f(){
            printf("just another hello");
        }
    };
__device__ void (*me)() =  &x::f;
```

the compiler said

```
error: a value of type "void (x::*)()" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "void (*)()"
```

Comment: that's pointer to member and is a completely different beast

Comment: A pointer to a class member function has the form `ret_type (class_name::*)(param_list)`

Comment: [Compiler error: cannot convert function pointer to typedef function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72541376/995714), [Pointer to class data member "::*"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/670734/995714), [Whats the point of pointers to member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72419105/995714)